# How to detect back button event?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

How to detect back button event when navigator.notification.confirm is opened? Back button just close pop-up, but event document.addEventListener('backbutton', onBackKeyDown, false); doesn't raised.

Comment: I have added a Phonegap tag because this is mainly Phonegap question. Also, this is not a critique but don't expect a solution without a code example, even if it is classified.

Answer (score 0):

In the `success` callback that you pass into the `navigator.notification.confirm` API, you can get the buttonIndex of which button was clicked. It's not documented, but if buttonIndex=0, then the user either clicked outside of the dialog to close it or clicked the Back button.

So for example:

```
  function makeConfirm(){
        navigator.notification.confirm(
            'You are the winner!',  // message
            onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
            'Game Over',            // title
            'Restart,Exit'          // buttonLabels
        );        
    }

    function onConfirm(buttonIndex){
        console.log("confirmation! Button clicked was:" + buttonIndex);
        if( buttonIndex===0 ){
            // they either hit back button or tapped the area outside of the dialog
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to determine whether they clicked the actual hardware back button or just clicked off the dialog. You could maybe register a click event on the body of the page and see if this got fired, if it did and `buttonIndex===0`, then they clicked outside of the dialog. If `buttonIndex===0` but it didn't get fired, they clicked the hardware back button.

I have also read on other questions on StackOverflow about using JQM to detect if the back button was pressed; maybe you can just use this.

Comment: It doesn't come into function for handling back button event when navigator.notification.confirm is active.